# Using Switch statements with a for loop and mouse click to change data returned by case

Tags: javascript, java, processing

I am trying to use a switch statement return different columns when a user mouse clicks. Currently I have it set that when the click(toggle==0) return column 2 which works. Then when the toggle ==1 return column 0, this is where the code is not working. I would expect my dataMax and dataMin to change between case:0 and case:1. When I manually change it for case 0: I see the values change as I would expect. Below is my code:

```
FloatTable locationTable;
FloatTable dataTable;
float dataMin = MAX_FLOAT;
float dataMax = MIN_FLOAT;
int rowCount;
int toggle = 0;
void setup() {
//   font = loadFont("Univers-Bold-12.vlw");
//   textFont(font);
   size(650,400);
dataTable = new FloatTable("povertynoheader.tsv");
   mapImage = loadImage("map.png"); 
   locationTable = new FloatTable("locations.tsv"); 
   rowCount = locationTable.getRowCount();
   // Read the data table.
       switch (toggle) {   
         case 0:
   // Find the minimum and maximum values.
   for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
     float value = dataTable.getFloat(row, 2);
     if (value > dataMax) {
       dataMax = value;
     }

     if (value < dataMin) {
       dataMin = value;
     } 
   }
   break;
   case 1:
      // Find the minimum and maximum values.
   for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
     float value = dataTable.getFloat(row, 0);
     if (value > dataMax) {
       dataMax = value;
     }

     if (value < dataMin) {
       dataMin = value;
     } 
   }
   break;

void mousePressed() {
  if (toggle == 0 ) {
    toggle = 1;

  } else {
    toggle = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not see the value of `toggle` getting changed to `1` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I updated my code to include the mousepressed code. This was just a snippet as my code is longer and the mouse press was further down.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash both examples you provided did not work for me.  I am still getting the same issues.

Comment: The Setup method run only once when you start the program (or if you call it yourself). It won't magically run to update these globals. [Take a look here, it will give you a chance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238572/using-a-switch-statement-with-a-for-loop-change-data-retrieved/62254972#62254972) I kinda stumbled on this problem while trying to help you with another problem and fixed it while I was at it without knowing that you had another question aimed at it elsewhere.